# An error while reading all files in folder on Android with Java

Tags: java, android, file, directory

My app crashes while running. I tried it on Android 5.1 (Lollipop). This app needs to read all files in the folder. The folder is download on sdcard.

Listview is working good, there is no error. The source is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] files = getAllFilesInFolder(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/download");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.LargeTextInList, files);
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new ItemList());
    }

    String[] getAllFilesInFolder(String path){
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(); //ArrayList cause you don't know how many files there is
        File folder = new File(path); //This is just to cast to a File type since you pass it as a String
        File[] filesInFolder = folder.listFiles(); // This returns all the folders and files in your path
        for (File file : filesInFolder) { //For each of the entries do:
            if (!file.isDirectory()) { //check that it's not a dir
                result.add(new String(file.getName())); //push the filename as a string
            }
        }

        String[] files = new String[ result.size() ];
        result.toArray( files );
        return files;
    }

    class ItemList implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) view;
            TextView tv = (TextView) vg.findViewById(R.id.LargeTextInList);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, tv.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the error? Post the crash logcat.

Comment: Are you define storage permission in android manifest ?

Comment: And for Android > 5 you should check for android runtime permissions. Maybe problem is in it. Reference: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: What is the error and what line of code causes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the permissions
 1) in your AndroidManifest add

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.example.myApp">   

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 ...
```

2)Then in your activity request the permissions this works from api 21+

```
private static final int PERMISSIONS_READ_STORE = 2;

private void requestPermissions() {
    String [] permissions=new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };
    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String permission:permissions) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,permission )!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(permission);
        }
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), PERMISSIONS_READ_STORE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    if(requestCode == PERMISSIONS_READ_STORE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
          // Permissions ok get the files
        }
    }else {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

Call requestPermissions() before you get the files